# How can I remove tab spacing from text for UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel, tabbing

I'm reading some text from a local xml file and displaying it in a UILabel. The text in the xml initially had tabbed spacing in it. I removed this tabbing manually in the editor but it's still showing up in the UILabel and it makes the text layout look very messy.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below

```
myLabel.text = [myText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the text to your label you can do this:

```
myLabel.text = [textWithTabs stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
```

This will remove the tabs completely.

Answer (score 0):

> stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
>   Returns a new string made by removing
>   from both ends of the receiver
>   characters contained in a given
>   character set.

```
- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set
```

[NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet%3a)